# How to initialize const containers with generators in modern C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, generator, c++17

In order to avoid mutable containers / states I currently wonder what's the closest thing to construct a `const` STL container from some input, e.g.

```
const vector<int> input = {2, 13, 7, 1};
```

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
const auto transformed = generate_from<vector<string>>(
    input.begin(), input.end(), to_string);

do_something(transformed);
```

While the approach you find the most would create a mutable object and modify it (what I'd like to avoid):

```
vector<string> bad_mutable_container;
for (const auto & elem : input) {
    bad_mutable_container.push_back(to_string(input[elem]));
};

do_something(bad_mutable_container);
```

C++11 and newer provide `std::generate` and `std::generate_n` but they operate on a mutable object, so they don't solve my problem:

```
vector<string> bad_mutable_container(input.size());
generate_n(bad_mutable_container.begin(), input.size(), [&input, n=0] () mutable {
    return to_string(input[n++]);
});
```

What you can do now is encapsulate that code in a function/lambda which gives you const-ness but also noisy boilerplate code:

```
const auto transformed = [&input] {
    vector<string> bad_mutable_container;
    for (const auto & elem : input) {
        bad_mutable_container.push_back(to_string(elem));
    };
    return bad_mutable_container;
} ();

do_something(transformed);
```

I've expected to find at least some constructor for e.g. `std::vector` which I can use like this:

```
const auto transformed = vector<string>(input.size(), [&input, n=0] () mutable {
    return to_string(input[n++]);
});
```

What would be the most modern C++ish approach to this today and why?

Comment: I guess Your solution with lambda is the best and simplest one. You can remove the `-> vector<string>` to remove some boilerplate, but that is the best You can do IMO

Comment: lambda is the way to do it. You can avoid typing `() -> vector<string>` as it can be ommited. Also the `move` call here prevents RVO.

Comment: The " most modern C++"  would be C++17, did you intentionally tag it with C++11? because the previous 2 comments are correct for C++17, but not for C++11

Comment: @bartop / Jaa-c / MSalters:  applied your recommendations

Comment: `boost::transform_iterator` should solve your mutability issue.

Comment: or use [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).

Comment: The lambda is the favorable way of doing it. writing a generic function is also an option.

Comment: FYI [`std::generate` and `_n` were already available in C++98. The only difference with C++11 is the return value.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate_n/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- With `boost::transform_iterator`, you may do:

  ```
  auto to_string_fun = [](const auto& e){ return std::to_string(e); };
  const std::vector output(boost::transform_iterator(input.begin(), to_string_fun),
                           boost::transform_iterator(input.end(), to_string_fun));
  ```

  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f33b3be881301f5b)
- With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may do:

  ```
   const std::vector<std::string> output = input
       | ranges::view::transform([](int e){ return std::to_string(e); });
  ```

  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3656c54f3eee767)

Comment: Hey Jarod, looks this answer helps you beyond 100k this week :). Maybe you consider adding the approach based on Boost-Range since your answer is the one read by the most..

Comment: Don't you mean `boost::make_transform_iterator`? I tried your first code, but had to modify it significantly to compile..

Comment: @JHBonarius: For boost example, I use C++17 which support template deduction guide. (so also `std::vector` instead of `std::vector<std::string>`). Prior to C++17, `make_transform_iterator` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. C++17 is too advanced for MSVC2017 ;) But [got gcc to work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DRl7CXU7IOXXqrR6)

Answer (score 4):

With the help of [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42)'s answer I found `boost::copy_range` together with `boost::adaptors::transformed` which can be used like [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3):

```
const auto transformed = boost::copy_range<vector<string>>(
        input |
        boost::adaptors::transformed([] (const auto &elem) { 
            return to_string(elem);}));
```

Since I'm already using Boost I'll go with this solution otherwise I certainly would use range-v3 until it's becoming standard :)